# Send file using php without exposing directory

Tags: php, apache, file, http-headers

These are my settings:

```
Web Server: Apache/2.4.25
Web structure:
 /
 |__Video/
         |__ test.mp4
 |__play.php
```

Currently I am exposing all my videos on my server putting directly the video directory in the apache directory.

What I want to obtain is to move the video outside the Apache directory (assume no permission problems) and trasmit only the requested video through a GET request to `play.php` like: `GET play.php?req=test.mp4`

Currently I've written the following code:

```php
$name = $_GET['req']
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($name));
header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($name));
header('Content-Disposition: filename="'.$name.'"');
readfile($name);
exit;
```

What is missing? Why do I get "No supported video media" when I try to access to the file using play.php? Using "mysite.com/Video/test.mp4" I can access directly to the media without problems.

I realized that if I wait a sufficient long time, the browser fully download the file and reproduce it. What I can't obtain is the streaming of the file.

Comment: What is the value of the call to `mime_content_type`? I suspect that it is not what you think it is. Have you tried specifying the correct mime type manually?

Comment: @Dave The mime_content_type extract the correct information, I checked using cUrl. Btw, to be sure i used the following: `'Content-Type: video/mp4'` without any changes. I realized that in both ways if I wait a sufficient long time, the browser fully download the file and reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem and a possible solution.

1. The problem is in the fileread, it trasmit the whole file before the browser can process it.
2. A possible workaround is the use of the `X-SendFile` module.

In case you use Debian like me is sufficient to:

- Install it: `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-xsendfile`
- Modify your site conf (Default path: `/ect/apache2/sites-available`) adding the following lines at the beginning (or to the chosen VirtualHost):

```
XSendFile on
XSendFilePath /full/path/to/directory1
XSendFilePath /full/path/to/directory2
```

- Restart the web server: `sudo systemctl reload apache2 && sudo systemctl restart apache2`
- Update the php script in this way:

```php
$name = "/full/path/to/directory1/".$_GET['req']
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($name));
header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($name));
header('Content-Disposition: filename="'.$name.'"');
header('X-Sendfile: $name');
```

For more information I suggest you to visit [this page](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/).